# vsftpd chroot_list_enable seems not to be considered

Tags: ftp

I am trying to set up a FTP server using vsftpd on CentOS 6.4

I created two users `joe` and `jane`, I'd like `joe` to be chrooted upon login while `jane` should not. For this matter I've written the following configuration

```
local_enable=YES
local_root=/var/ftp
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
```

The content of my chroot_list is :

```
joe
```

Using this configuration, every login users get chrooted, when I was expecting to get `joe` chrooted and `jane` in `/var/ftp`

What am I missing ?

Comment: does it work if you set `chroot_local_user=YES` and put `jane` in the `chroot_list_file`?

Comment: If I do this both `jane` and `joe` get chrooted